# Multilabel class fails with same dataset while multiclass model can succeed

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, training-data, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I am training a Graph convolutional neural network. A classifier is connected to the end of this network and when I try to train the whole model as a single (multiclass), I can achieve great success of 91% (F1 weighted score).
[image: Single (Multiclass) model]

But when I try to train the same model as multilabel, both the training time of the model is much longer and the model fails.
[image]

Classifier code is as follows, it works separately according to single or multi.

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_size, tag_size, args, pred_type='SINGLE'):
    super(Classifier, self).__init__()
    self.emotion_att = MaskedEmotionAtt(input_dim)
    self.lin1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_size)
    self.drop = nn.Dropout(args.drop_rate)
    self.lin2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, tag_size)
    self.pred_type = pred_type
    if args.class_weight:
        self.loss_weights = (torch.rand(tag_size) * 9 + 1).to(args.device)
        if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
            self.loss_func = nn.NLLLoss(self.loss_weights)
        elif self.pred_type == 'MULTI':
            self.loss_func = nn.BCELoss(self.loss_weights)
    else:
        if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
            self.loss_func = nn.NLLLoss()
        elif self.pred_type == 'MULTI':
            self.loss_func = nn.BCELoss()

def get_prob(self, h, text_len_tensor):
    # h_hat = self.emotion_att(h, text_len_tensor)
    hidden = self.drop(F.relu(self.lin1(h)))
    scores = self.lin2(hidden)
    if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
        log_prob = F.log_softmax(scores, dim=-1)
    elif self.pred_type == 'MULTI':
        log_prob = F.sigmoid(scores)
    else:
        return scores
    return log_prob

def forward(self, h, text_len_tensor):
    log_prob = self.get_prob(h, text_len_tensor)
    if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
        y_hat = torch.argmax(log_prob, dim=-1)
    elif self.pred_type == 'MULTI':
        y_hat = []
        for pred in log_prob:
            y_hat.append([1 if p > 0.5 else 0 for p in pred.flatten().tolist()])

        y_hat = torch.tensor(y_hat)
    try:
        y_hat
    except NameError:
        log.error('Prediction type should be one of these [\'SINGLE\', \'MULTI\']')
    return y_hat


def get_loss(self, h, label_tensor, text_len_tensor):
    log_prob = self.get_prob(h, text_len_tensor)
    if self.pred_type == 'SINGLE':
        loss = self.loss_func(log_prob, label_tensor)
    elif self.pred_type == 'MULTI':
        loss = self.loss_func(log_prob, label_tensor.float())
    return loss
```

Comment: BCEWithLogtisLoss ?

Comment: isn'T BCEWithLogitsLoss using without sigmoid?

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html - This loss combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single class

Comment: https://androidkt.com/difference-between-bceloss-and-bcewithlogitsloss-in-pytorch/ as i see from here, there is no need bcewithlogitsloss if i use sigmoid layer already, it gives exactly same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multilabel and Single datasets can create differences when evaluating a no-label class in the data.

In my example, only 20% of the contents had labels. I was putting a representative 0-label for those without a label. While these 0 values ​​were not included in multilabel training, single was also included. For this reason, the single dataset quickly reached a success of 85% by predicting 0s more.

In addition, reducing the model complexity (number of layers, number of neurons) also increases the number of training epochs, but faster fit.
and resulted in less overfit.